# How to measure the usage of disk cache?

Tags: hard-disk, disk-usage, proc, cache, load

Load Average itself is not very informative about the reasons of overload, so I want an additional characteristic: the percent of disk read operations that are done from cache. To measure it, I probably need:

- the amount of data read from cache (or, instead, the amount of data read directly from disk);
- the total amount of read data.

Both for the certain period of time, f.e., 1 second.

Is this information available in procfs/sysfs?

Answer (score 1):

Use `cachestat-perf` from [perf-tools](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools).

```
# cachestat-perf                                       
Counting cache functions... Output every 1 seconds.
    HITS   MISSES  DIRTIES    RATIO   BUFFERS_MB   CACHE_MB
    2086       47        0    97.8%            5        541
    1952        0        0   100.0%            5        541
    1851        0        0   100.0%            5        541
    1904        0        0   100.0%            5        541
    1903        0        0   100.0%            5        541
```

Comment: Needs a custom kernel with `CONFIG_FUNCTION_PROFILER` enabled :(

Answer (score 1):

`sar -r --human 1` should give you the information you're looking for in the `kbdirty` column. The man page has a lot of detail on the different commands that are available.